# What are the differences between Jupyter Classic Notebook launched from JupyterLab v3.6.3 "Help" menu and Jupyter Classic Notebook from command line?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-nbclassic

I have a question about the Jupyter Classic Notebook client bundled into the JuptyerLab "Help" menu, and the Jupyter Classic Notebook client launched from a Windows Command Console.

What are the differences in functionality between these two versions of simple Jupyter Notebook?

1. I start JupyterLab Version 3.6.3 from Windows cmd terminal.
2. I launch Jupyter Classic Notebook from the JupyterLab "Help" menu, it opens the Jupyter Classic Notebook "Dashboard".
3. I create a new Jupyter Notebook document from the "New" dropdown menu.
4. I check the Jupyter Classic Notebook version by typing `!jupyter nbclassic --version` in a Windows terminal (console window), and it shows 0.5.5.  Checking it from the Help menu in the notebook gives the same 0.5.5 version.

Doing the following command in another one of my conda virtual enviornments I get similar "different" Jupyter Notebook Client versions.

> (dtale_demo) c:\Users\PowerUser>jupyter lab --version
> 3.6.3
>
> (dtale_demo) c:\Users\PowerUser>jupyter notebook --version
> 6.5.4
>
> (dtale_demo) c:\Users\PowerUser>jupyter nbclassic  --version
> 0.5.5

This is a bit surprising to me.  I thought it would be the same Jupyter Classic Notebook launched from the command line.

When I check the Help "About..." menu in JupyterLab I get:

You are using Jupyter NbClassic.

> The version of the Jupyter server is: 2.5.0 To get the version of
> nbclassic, run in a terminal: jupyter nbclassic --version The server
> is running on this version of Python: Python 3.10.0 | packaged by
> conda-forge | (default, Nov 20 2021, 02:18:13) [MSC v.1916 64 bit
> (AMD64)]

So, my question is "What are the real differences in functionality between the traditional (pre-JupyterLab) Jupyter Classic Notebook and the Jupyter Classic Notebook ("nbclassic") available from the JupyterLab Help... menu "Launch Jupyter Notebook" selection?

Answer (score 0):

The question is of historical value now, since from version 4.0.0 of JupyterLab, the "Launch Classic Notebook" option is gone for good (and so is the duality of these two modes of running Jupyter Notebook).

Comment: Thanks for responding.   I am upgrading my environment to see what the differences are.